# How do I find the vertices of the largest hexagon that can be inscribed into a square?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Some days my brain just doesn't feel like working and this is one of them. I have a problem. I want to make a hexagon that would fit exactly within a square for whatever reason, whether it be for a logo, or for an engineering problem. Doesn't matter.

Now I know from intuition that the hexagon must be oriented at a 45 degree (or 1/4 radian) angle. I just want to know where I should be putting the points that hexagon would be inscribed into, in traditional cartesian coordinates, based on my square's side length of A.

Now that I know what I want to do, how would I find those positions and prove that they're where my hexagon's points should be located?

This question should be easy, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. The solutions I came across so far detail the *area* of the hexagon in question, and among the proofs for area I observed, I figured out that the points intersecting the square boundary should be

```
    corner + sidelength / (1 + sqrt(3))
```

However, the trigonometry required to find the points for the vertices not intersecting the square border around the shape still eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these are what you are looking for:

[enter link description here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-hexagon-that-can-be-inscribed-within-a-square/)

[enter link description here](http://www.drking.org.uk/hexagons/misc/deriv4.html)